# My Sql merging rows

Tags: mysql, rows

How can I query merge rows which has same dates and get rid of null

```
Date       | Long | Short
2006-07-06 | t1   |
2006-07-06 |      | t2
2006-07-05 | t1   | 
2006-07-05 |      | t2
2006-07-04 | t1   |
2006-07-04 |      | t2
2006-07-03 | t1   | 
2006-07-03 |      | t2
```

to this

```
Date       | Long | Short
2006-07-06 | t1   | t2
2006-07-05 | t1   | t2
2006-07-04 | t1   | t2
2006-07-03 | t1   | t2
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
SELECT `date`, MAX(`long`) `long`, MAX(short) short
FROM yourtable
GROUP BY `date`
```

Comment: Sorry for taking long to get back, i just finished and it was the weekend, Thank you for the help it worked, thanks again

Answer (score 0):

One approach to getting the specified resultset, is using a GROUP BY and aggregate functions:

```
SELECT t.Date
     , MAX(t.Long) AS `Long`
     , MAX(t.Short) AS `Short`
  FROM mytable t
 GROUP
    BY t.Date
```