# Merge Rows By Group

Tags: mysql, sql, merge, group-by

I have weather data from weather stations in all the states.

[image: db model]

Here is a basic query I've been running.

```
-- Weather pattern for continental US    
SELECT 
    YEAR(Date), 
    MONTH(Date),
    DataType,
    AVG(Value)
FROM 
    Station_Data 
WHERE
    Stations_ID NOT IN (
        SELECT 
            Stations.ID 
        FROM 
            Stations 
        JOIN States
            States 
        ON 
            States.ID = Stations.States_ID 
        WHERE 
            States.Name = "Alaska" OR States.Name = "Hawaii"
    ) AND
    YEAR(Date) = 2000
GROUP BY 
    YEAR(Date), 
    MONTH(Date),
    DataType;
```

and the output is the following

[image: Result 1]

I want to convert the output to have separate columns for MMNT, MMXT, MNTM. I tried using solutions provided in [Efficiently convert rows to columns in sql server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15745042/efficiently-convert-rows-to-columns-in-sql-server) and [My Sql merging rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17618143/my-sql-merging-rows)

```
-- Weather pattern for continental US    
SELECT 
    YEAR(Date), 
    MONTH(Date),
    AVG(CASE WHEN (DataType = "MMNT") THEN Value ELSE 0 END) AS MMNT,
    AVG(CASE WHEN (DataType = "MMXT") THEN Value ELSE 0 END) AS MMXT,
    AVG(CASE WHEN (DataType = "MNTM") THEN Value ELSE 0 END) AS MNTM
FROM 
    Station_Data 
WHERE
    Stations_ID NOT IN (
        SELECT 
            Stations.ID 
        FROM 
            Stations 
        JOIN States
            States 
        ON 
            States.ID = Stations.States_ID 
        WHERE 
            States.Name = "Alaska" OR States.Name = "Hawaii"
    ) AND
    YEAR(Date) = 2000
GROUP BY 
    YEAR(Date), 
    MONTH(Date),
    DataType;
```

but my result looks like this...

[image: Result 2]

what's wrong with the statement?

**-- UPDATE**

I tried removing DataType from GROUP and I get this result...

[image: Result 4]

But I think the value is wrong.

```
SELECT 
    AVG(Value)
FROM 
    Station_Data 
WHERE
    Stations_ID NOT IN (
        SELECT 
            Stations.ID 
        FROM 
            Stations 
        JOIN States
            States 
        ON 
            States.ID = Stations.States_ID 
        WHERE 
            States.Name = "Alaska" OR States.Name = "Hawaii"
    ) 
    AND YEAR(Date) = 2000
    AND MONTH(Date) = 1
    AND DataType = "MMNT";
```

[image: Result 5]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to group by `DataType`. This is the answer. Otherwise your aggregate function works within single value of the type, so you are always geting one column that is not zero.

Comment: I tried that, but it seems like the value changes. I updated the post with your suggestion.

Comment: Update your conditions to ` THEN Value ELSE NULL END`. 0's gets counted in average but NULLs will be ignored.

Comment: In aggregate don't do `else 0`