# SQL - merge rows into one?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I am trying to build a report from an old, badly structured telephony system. The table structure I have is below

```
 User         Interval                          Logon                            Logoff
 3356        2020-03-27 08:45:00.000            2020-03-27 08:51:45.0620000      NULL
 3356        2020-03-27 09:00:00.000            NULL                             NULL
 3356        2020-03-27 09:15:00.000            NULL                             NULL
 3356        2020-03-27 09:30:00.000            NULL                             2020-03-27 09:32:23.000   
 3356        2020-03-27 09:45:00.000            NULL                             NULL
 3356        2020-03-27 10:00:00.000            2020-03-27 10:11:25.0620000      NULL
 3356        2020-03-27 10:15:00.000            NULL                             2020-03-27 10:11:18.0620000
```

The data is grouped by 15 minute chunks and shows any log ons or log offs that have occurred during those 15 minutes. What I want to do is produce an output that puts any logons on the same row as their next log offs. My output would look like the below.

```
 User         Interval                          Logon                            Logoff
 3356        2020-03-27                        2020-03-27 08:51:45.0620000       2020-03-27 09:32:23.000   
 3356        2020-03-27                        2020-03-27 10:11:25.0620000       2020-03-27 10:11:18.0620000
```

I tried the solution here ([My Sql merging rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17618143/my-sql-merging-rows)) but this was just giving me the first log on and last log off for the entire day - missing things in between.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `lead()` and filtering.  Assuming the values are correctly interleaved:

```
select user, convert(date, interval), logon
       coalesce(logoff, next_logoff) as logoff
from (select t.*, 
             lead(logoff) over (partition by user order by interval) as next_logoff
      from t
      where logon is not null or logoff is not null
     ) t
where logon is not null;
```

This should also handle the situation when the `logoff` and `logon` are in the same interval.